# Are either of my guppies pregnant?

Tags: aquarium, fish, breeding

Bottom one seems to be, but I'm not positive. Please help me, I need to know before she pops!

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think both of your guppies seem to be pregnant (technically formal term in this case is not pregnant, but "gravid"). And yes, it's hard to tell in the upper one, because their natural black colouring is the same as that of a gravid spot, but I think these are visible in both of your fish. Please see the linked question for more information.

Comment: both of your guppys are pregnant the only guppys that are not pregnant is called males :) why do you need to know if they are pregnant,you can not do anything about it,if you want to take care of the babies you need to give the babies hiding places like plants and decoration in your tank.

Comment: please take a look at this to learn about guppys https://aquariumadviser.com/how-to-tell-if-guppies-are-pregnant/ and how to care for the babies